# Calculating Lebesgue integral 2

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

How can we calculate Lebesgue integral; for example, when we have $\mu(x)=x^2$ and $ f(x)=x $  $(\int f(x) \mu(dx)  = \int x (dx)^2)$  ?

can we use $ \int f(x) \mu(dx)=\int fd\mu $ ,instead of solving $\int x (dx)^2$, calculate $\int x\times2x(dx)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu(x)=x^2$? Do you mean that for an interval $[a,b)$ $\mu([a,b))=b^2-a^2$?

Comment: Image $\mu$ as a intensity function. In your example $\mu([a,b])=(b-a)^2$

Comment: For example, we have $[x,x+dx]$. Therefore expected number of points located in this segment is $(dx)^2$.

Comment: This $\mu$ is not a measure. Let $a<b<c$ be reals. If $\mu$ is a measure then $\mu([a,c))=\mu([a,b))+\mu([b,c))$. But $(c-a)^2=?(b-a)^2+(c-b)^2$. NO: $c^2-2ac+a^2\not=b^2-2ab+a^2+c^2-2cb+b^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what does $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ means? $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function and $\mu(dx)$ is expected number of points falling in $dx$ (intensity function of point process).  Mathematically we calculate $f(x)\times\mu(dx)$ and add them together but I want to know what it physically means and what the physical result is (comparing with the situations when we say integral calculates the area of the function...)

Comment: What if give you an "official answer now? (As I know what you are interested in...)

Comment: What do you mean by "official answer now"?

Comment: Official means simply that I give you a an Answer and take the risk of being down vote if the community won't like my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the fundamental problem with your question is that you try to define a kind of integral of a function ($f$) with respect to something ($\mu$) which is not  a measure. In a comment above I showed that $"\mu(x)=x^2"$ as a set function defined on intervals by

$$\mu([a,b))=(b-a)^2$$

was not a measure. The concept of the integral of functions with respect to set functions is restricted to specific set functions called measures.

---

What is a measure and what does it have to do with probability? It is impossible to present measure theory here. It is easy to demonstrate, however, that if we want to model probabilities (of numbers falling into sets of reals) then we need special set functions.

---

So, let $r_n(A)$ denote the relative frequency of an event that a random number fell in the set $A$. The most important property that we claim $r_n(A)$ to have are as follows:

1. $$1\ge r_n(A)\ge 0.$$
2. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets then $$r_n(A\cup B)=r_n(A)+r_n(B).$$
3. $$r_n(\mathbb R)=1, \ \mathbb R \text{ being the real line}.$$

If the set function $\mu$ does not have these properties then it cannot be used as a model of the distribution of a real valued random variable.

---

Your integral

$$\int_{\mathbb R} x\mu(dx)$$

is supposed to model the average of independent random trials. This is easy to (intuitively) see.

Imagine that $k_1, k_2,...k_m$ are the actual numbers that the random number fell into the pairwise disjoint sets $A_1, A_2,...A_m$ ($\bigcup_{k=1}^m=\mathbb R$), respectively. Also, let's select representative reals $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ from the sets $A_1, A_2,...A_m$ and let's agree that we will represent the random result by $x_k$ if the actual value of the random variable fell into the set $A_k$. If we had $n$ experiments then the average can be written as a sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m r_n(A_k)x_k\approx \int_{\mathbb R} x\mu(dx)$$

if $\mu$ as a set function well represents the probabilities of falling into corresponding sets.

---

An example: Suppose that our random variable fall within the interval $[-1,1]$ surely. Then because of condition 3. we have to use a function generating a measure like the following one. Let

$$\mu(x)=\begin{cases}
0,& \text{ if } x<-1\\
\frac12 x^3+\frac12,& \text{ if } -1\le x\le1\\
1,& \text{ if } x>1.\\
\end{cases}$$

Then, for an interval $[a,b]\subset [-1,1]$, let the probability of falling into $[a,b]$ be modeled by

$$\mu([a,b])=\frac12(b^3-a^3).$$

The expected value of our random phenomenon (an approximation of an actual average) is

$$\int_{-1}^1 x \ \mu(dx)=\int_{-1}^1 x \ \frac{\mu(dx)}{dx}\ dx=$$
$$\int_{-1}^1 x \ \frac{d (\frac12x^3+\frac12)}{dx}\ dx=\int_{-1}^1 x \ \frac32x^2\ dx=\frac32\int_{-1}^1 \ x^3 \ dx=0.$$

This argumentation was more than sketchy.

---

If you want to understand these kinds of things  better then start with : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics).

Comment: What does  $\mu(dx)$ maen? is it the measure of $dx$? Then what does $d\mu$ means?

Comment: In this sketchy set up $\mu(dx)\approx \mu([x,x+\Delta x))$. $d \mu$ is the same. But without studying the theory of Lebesgue's integral theory or general measure theory these are just hints.

Comment: Imagine our ground set is $[-3,3]$ and $A_i$s are $...,[-1,0),[0,1),[1,2),...$ . if they are equally probable we have $r_n(A_i)=1/6$. then if our random numbers are $1.9,2.1,...$ the integral will be equal to $1/6\times(1.9+2.1+...)$. is this true? so it gives us the expected number? In general when $f$ is measurable function what does this integral mean?

Comment: More exactly you are talking about three values of equal probability. (Then the sets are unnecessary). I was talking about a sequence of random results and a relatively fine subdivision of the "ground set". The representative elements belonging to the sets were not the only possible values. However, as the subdivision gets finer the integral approximates the the better the average.

Comment: It was Just an example. do you have any idea about last two questions?

Comment: I cannot interpret the last two questions ($ \int f(x) \mu(dx)=\int fd\mu $ ,instead of solving $\int x (dx)^2$, calculate $\int x\times2x(dx)$) It is strongly advised that you start studying measure theory. Sorry, I cannot go any further...

Comment: I mean these two questions: so it gives us the expected number? In general when f is measurable function what does this integral mean?

Comment: $\int f d\mu$ is a generalized version of the Riemann integral. Ig $f$ is integrable in the Riemann sense and if $d\mu=dx$ (is the Lebesgue measure) then the two integrals equal.